# How to extract strings only containing a specific word?

Tags: r

I am trying to only pull the descriptions that contain the word "bunt". I am unsure how to do this as the word varies in position throughout my large dataset. Here is a sample of what I am working with:

```
   data <-data.frame(des=c("Austin Hedges bunt single", "Francisco Lindor Homerun", 
                           "Pete Alonso out on a ground ball bunt", 
                           "Yonathan Daza sac bunt ground out to shortstop", "Jose 
                           Ramirez pop up to second baseman"))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` to find the word and `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(data, grepl("\\bbunt\\b", des))
```

-output

```
                                            des
1                      Austin Hedges bunt single
3          Pete Alonso out on a ground ball bunt
4 Yonathan Daza sac bunt ground out to shortstop
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) and [`stringr`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/) packages, here's a solution.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(stringr)

data <-data.frame(des=c("Austin Hedges bunt single", "Francisco Lindor Homerun", 
                        "Pete Alonso out on a ground ball bunt", 
                        "Yonathan Daza sac bunt ground out to shortstop",
                        "Jose Ramirez pop up to second baseman"))

data %>%
  filter(stringr::str_detect(des, "bunt"))
#>                                              des
#> 1                      Austin Hedges bunt single
#> 2          Pete Alonso out on a ground ball bunt
#> 3 Yonathan Daza sac bunt ground out to shortstop
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>